# Succinctly comparing and partially merging configuration trees

Tags: parsing, configuration, diff

I would like to succinctly diff a tree of configuration files, most of which are flat (i.e. key/value pairs) but some of which are XML, bash scripts or custom formats. The configuration information is almost always not ordered, and can contain whitespace and comments.

For flat files, doing a diff without whitespace or comments on sorted output gets very close to what I would like to do. For XML there are [some](http://diffxml.sourceforge.net/) [tools](http://www.logilab.org/859) [available](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_diff_and_merge.html). However some custom formats have e.g. nested configuration. Order of the keys is not important, order of the subkeys is not important, but the tree structure is (much like XML). Others are very order-dependent.

How would you go about doing this if you had to do it often? Are there any tools out there that are general enough? What about rolling my own solution? The number of formats is nor enormous (certainly not as bad as /etc), and the default is flat - perhaps some libmagic and filename matching, combined with custom parsers? Has anyone tried something like that?

One approach would be to try to solve 95% of the problem by doing a decent job on files with nested but unnordered structure and special-casing a few other types with existing tools. Can you suggest a mostly-works approach to simple nested files?

**Some examples:**

```
com.example.resource.host=foo
com.example.resource.port=8080
```

vs

```
com.example.resource.port=8080
com.example.resource.host=bar
//com.example.network.timeout=600
com.example.network.timeout=300
```

Should produce

```
< com.example.resource.host=foo
---
> com.example.resource.host=bar
> //com.example.network.timeout=600
> com.example.network.timeout=300
```

or optionally:

```
< com.example.resource.host=foo
---
> com.example.resource.host=bar
> com.example.network.timeout=300
```

as you would expect. However, something like:

```
Conf com.example.resource =
    Conf host = foo;
    Conf port = 8080;
;
```

vs

```
Conf com.example.resource =
    Conf port = 8080;
    Conf host = bar;
;
Conf com.example.network =
    Conf timeout = 300;
;
```

Should also work:

```
<     Conf host = foo
---
>     Conf host = bar
> Conf com.example.network =
>     Conf timeout = 300;
> ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Each of your configuration files has a syntax and an implied semantics.  It appears that what you want to do, is to compare configuration files by the implied semantics rather than the text.

The only way to do this is have a custom parser for each configuration file type.  Then you need compare the files according to the implied semantics.

In general, this is pretty hard to do, certainly for real programming languages. We offer a compromise solution, call [SmartDifferencers](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SmartDifferencer) that parse code according the precise langauge syntax, and then compares them according to the language structures (e.g, expressions, statements, declarations, methods, ...), reporting differences as abstract editing operations (move, copy, delete, insert, rename-identifier within a block).  This gives succint deltas (which is what you asked for) in terms that make sense to programmers, rather than just "this block of lines changed somehow" typical of diff.

These tools know the language syntax, and they know a *tiny* bit of the semantics; in particular, we try (and we're not completely there for all of them) to handle the notion
of *commutative* language elements.  In Java, the order of methods in a class is immaterial. In your case, the order of some configuration elements are likely immaterial.  Our machinery can take this into account.

To do this for what *you* want to do, you need a separate parser for each type of configuration file, and separate knowledge for each type of when you can shuffle commands around safely.  You need a separate tool for each type of configuration file to do this right.  (Those files that are XML-based, in effect need separtes tools because you are trying to distinguish semantics as well as syntax.).   Your ideal solution, I think, are SmartDifferencers for each of your configuration file types.